# Android: Queue a post until there is a connection

Tags: java, android, sdk, http-post, internet-connection

hi this is a very simple question but a complicated answer I suspect:

It's called the "mineshaft scenario"

Let me explain : imagine a simple scenario where you had to make a app that can httppost to a webpage even down a mine shaft with no signal.

i.e. How do I try/queue a submit event (HTTPPOST) if there is no connection and then poll the queue periodically (test for presence of connection) until the event can fire.

**PS: be warned: please this is about "how to" not a dialogue as to the "wrongness" of this, re: synchronicity or duplicate records or overwriting data from 2 users etc etc.**

Pseudo Code:

```
try{
   MyHttpFileUploader myupload = new MyHttpFileUploader();
   myupload.Start();
}
catch (InternetDownException ex){ //<-- how do I "throw" this in the start method gracefully?
   GlobalQueue.Add(myupload); //<-- how do i set a timer properly that can action this queue (.Start() method) and post messages "when complete" to toast on the main ui thread but otherwise not block the ui whatsoever
}
```

Comment: Silly question but you have heard about threading obviously(?). What's the problem in spawning a thread to deal with this (and if the application is possibly going to shutdown before completion then you should store state and on application start resume based on stored state). Also - what do you mean by "how do I "throw" this in the start method gracefully?"... You have already caught it... so either deal with the exception (by starting the thread) or re-throw it to be caught later)

Comment: the http post is already an async event. This is not UI de-bunging. This is good post polling much missing from the examples in forums. Threaded or not the post fails if there is no internet connection, this needs to NOT fail but retry after "x" amount of time and rinse repeat until successful. The workflow is exactly the one an email uses for it's outbox. And texts use for their sending. Rinse repeat until ok from server. I don't mind if it only rinse/repeats while the app is active in the UI thread, or whether it polls forever in the background regardless of user interaction.

Comment: In this regard it has nothing whatsoever to do with saved instance states or user application interaction once they initiate the post.

Comment: I have made threads do exactly what you are talking about - contact forms that store failed attempts to send via the mail server polling until the mail sever comes back online - yours is a classic long running threaded situation. whether or not the post is async once it excepts that is the end of the async post and you must provide fallback if you require further behaviour. I believe you should be using thread once the post fails.

Comment: ok but a) it's not a mail server it's a http post to a webserver b) if you're willing to share some of your code i'd love to borrow it - care to submit an answer? and c) the threading is not *really* the point other than the de-cluttering the ui thread which is out side the OP. What is needed is a Queue  (which is is, by definition not in the ui thread) that retries until complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rough (because I now mainly code in c# and it wouldn't be pertinent to the question) semi psuedo-code with sun documentation snippets on the main point (thread)

Create a class that has access to whatever variables are required in your async post method that extends Thread i.e.

```
 class WorkerThread extends Thread {
     int someDataYouNeed;
     MyHttpFileUploader maybeAClassYouNeedToCommunicateWithAtEnd;
     boolean hasNotFinishedTask = true;
     WorkerThread(int someDataYouNeed, MyHttpFileUploader callBackClass) {
         this.someDataYouNeed = someDataYouNeed;
         this.maybeAClassYouNeedToCommunicateWithAtEnd = callBackClass;
     }

     public void run() {

         while(hasNotFinishedTask){
         //do your work in here 
         //Try contact network endpoint
         try{
             //do a network call and if it doesnt except
             hasNotFinishedWork = false
             //now callback to the class firing a method maybe (I just made one up)
             maybeAClassYouNeedToCommunicateWithAtEnd.Close();
         }catch(TheException ex){ //do nothing or log }
         if(hasNotFinishedTask){
              Thread.Sleep(60000);//retry every minute
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

//instantiate the thread when your asynch task fails....

```
 WorkerThread worker = new WorkerThread(42, this);
 worker.start();
```

Now as I said - I assume your application is running on a smartphone and can be shut down... if that is the case and as long as the os allows it you may way to save state (when you create the WorkerThread) as i.e. xml in the filesystem and on the WorkerThread instantiation check if the file exists and start from where it left when it was shutdown.

On point a) Even though my example was a mail server they are both networking endpoints that can be unavailable

UPDATE:

Now I assumed that it would be straight java (and remember I'm c# so not on the platform that often) but it appears as if there is easy examples of Async generic types for this stuff in newer version of java or for android...

see [this blog post for android specific multi-threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) or doa google search for Android multi-threading for platform specific examples

Comment: and on your 'must be a queue' comment... in the WorkerThread run method you could i.e. work through a list of 'things' (i.e. maybe a List<T> you supply to the WorkerThread constructor, maybe a list of stuff in an xml file...) and when the thread has completed them all - exit.

Comment: I will give you the points - for the simple sleep while loop as a timer, nice and easy - but I will come back and link what I ended up doing

Comment: I'd be interested to see what other strategy you come up with :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use  [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to trigger trying to send the data.

There is more information here about using Intents [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) and the Intent could be triggered by the AlarmManager

There are also some code samples on this thread [AlarmManager not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684077/alarmmanager-not-working)

Comment: Thanks Rod, I sincerely think this needs to be a tutorial - one for "getting and caching http" json/images/content and one for queue-posting json back.. done properly in a "mineshaft" way i.e. make the app work and just alert the connection is down.. I am working towards this.. a proper tutorial on how to make connection independent http events.. considering java is a "error managed" language it's appalling that the powers-that-be don't battle over this for end-user programmers

Comment: Agreed, I am looking at doing something similar.