# How to restart application at specefic time

Tags: android

I have a service and some activity for that , I want whole application will restart at specific time  like (03:00 pm), do you know any way to to do this , so at 3AM , the whole app restart ?

thanks

Comment: because of memory leaks , so users system do not be slow . every time my app starts , it makes some small memory .

Comment: Maby this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452565/start-app-at-a-specific-time

Comment: Why don't you just fix the memory leaks? :/

Comment: what you have try for this bez this is easy to start an service at specific time by using AlarmManager?

Comment: @kcopp , it seem that there is a problem in android , why when I start activity and do nothing , and closing , it stores information and keep old used memories ???

Comment: You should handle that during the lifecycle methods (onPause(), onDestroy(), etc.) I don't mean this rudely, but most likely the problem is not with Android but with your app. Restarting the app on a timer may WORK, but it's not the appropriate solution. Think for example what happens if a user is interacting with the application at 3:00 AM? Try to find what information is being stored after closing the app, and then from there find out *why* it is being stored, and from there, correct it.

Comment: Kcopp , he should sleep at 3.00 AM , what he want from my app !:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use popular time based scheduler Cron found in unix/linux. by default it it is not active.need some hack inside. but i think you can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) This is a system service.

```
AlarmManager myAlarmManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE).
```

And if you need to stay alive after system reboot . Then you have to schedule he alarm after the device reboots.And need to have the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission in your AndroidManifest.xml