# How to automatically start an application at a fixed time in android?

Tags: android

I want to start my application everyday at a particular fixed time.i tried the link
[Start app at a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452565/start-app-at-a-specific-time) but didn't worked.

Comment: Have you tried out any code before?

Comment: see pendingintent and alarmanager and Broadcastreciever and may be intent as well....

Comment: i tried the link that i mentioned above but that is not what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By use of [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) you can declare the time. And use of  [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) you can start the application at the time of reached. I suggest you to try [Commonsware](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) example application. There you should modify the code by yourself with your needs.

Hope this helps you lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should achieve it using a service with `AlarmManger` for that.
First when user install your application then you should start `Service` then service start `AlarmManager` content a `pendingIndent` this pending intent fire on you specific  time mention you in `AlarmManager`