# How to launch my app every day at some particular time?

Tags: android, automation, background-process

I want to create an app which basicly, should launch itself at some particular time, do some stuff in background and after that kill itself.

I need a hint in which direction to move and what to read. I'm sorry for kinda dump question, but I'm a total beginner with android. So any reply would be great.

Comment: Check `AlarmManager` in Android doc.

Comment: See [this related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452565/start-app-at-a-specific-time). You'll have to modify it some to make it happen every day, but the basics are there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager

Comment: [This blog post](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/scheduling-an-application-to-start-later/) may help you find the solution.

Comment: Just curious, but what would be a good reason for an app to do something each day without the user knowing about it? Sounds a lot like spyware ;)

Comment: well no, app will check through contacts if anyone got birthday today:))

Comment: granted, legitimate request ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

also you can refere to this thread [Android: How to use AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager)

Comment: You should include some more details in your answer instead of just linking to other resources.