# how to start voice record for specific period of time

Tags: android

as new to android and had a requirement to start voice recording for specific period of time and the time will get by the button click by the user choice i had design the UI with several button with some second of time.so while clicking the button the time will set and recording will start.Is anything is there in android.Little help will be much appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

If I didn't misread it again, take a look at [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html). After creating your recorder instance, run below code

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        recorder.stop();
                        recorder.reset();
                        recorder.release();
                    }
                });

            }
}, longDelayInMilliseconds);
```

**Answer Before Edit**

I think [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is what you are looking for. As it says in the overview

> allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future

Take a look at these threads and blog entry.

[Start app at a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452565/start-app-at-a-specific-time)

[Android: How to use AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager)

[Schedule app to start later](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/scheduling-an-application-to-start-later/)

Comment: nothing to do with alarmmanager but to stop the recording after given period of time.Anyways found something in stacktrace and thank you for replies it will be helpfull may in future

Comment: Thanks for notifying me. It seems I misunderstood your question, I edited my answer.