# Start an app daily / on a specific time

Tags: android, android-service

I know that an application can be started on boot by receiving the intent `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`.

[Documentation link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED)

I am developing an app which I want to start daily say at 6 AM.

My question is, is `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` enough for this? I mean suppose user doesn't reboots the phone daily. So how to make sure that my app is started daily in the morning ?

As far as I know an alternative is to keep running a service such as [this](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)

But if I use that how much resource you think it will consume slowing down overall performance (keeping in mind my app runs always) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use your app as an alarm

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452565/start-app-at-a-specific-time?rq=1

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is just what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Alarm Manager for this as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452565/start-app-at-a-specific-time)

Also don't forget to re-register the alarm when the app is rebooted.